# Можно ли узнать имя активности из которой запустился AlertDialog

Tags: java, android

Я запускаю из любой активности `AlertDialog` функцию, передаю ей `context(this)`, `название`, `иконку`, и вот как мне узнать имя `активности` из функции, я так думаю поможет `context`, но как?

Answer (score 2):

Может кому-нибудь понадобится `context.getClass().getSimpleName()`, работает! даже к логам прикрутил...